# Query to find employee who worked on only one month

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table which has emp_id and Month, below is the sample data

| `emp_id` | `month` |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan |
| 1 | Feb |
| 2 | Jan |
| 2 | Feb |
| 3 | Feb |

Question is, how to find an employee who worked on only Feb. Expected output is 3 Feb.

Comment: You can select emp_id from table where emp_id in (select emp_id from table where month='FEB') and emp_id not in (select emp_id from table where month != 'FEB')

Comment: You don't have a year?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the data, you can use aggregation:

```
select emp_id
from t
group by emp_id
having min(month) = 'Feb' and max(month) = 'Feb'
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score -1):

```
select emp_id
from t
group by emp_id
having count(distinct month)=1
```

Can also find employees who only worked in 1 other month.